# Problem in accesing key values in dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array called objects:

```
  { x: 1, y: 1 },
  { x: 2, y: 3 },
  { x: 3, y: 3 },
  { x: 3, y: 4 },
  { x: 4, y: 5 }
];
```

Now if i want to access the key of the first dict, then I write

```
console.log(objects[1]['x'])
// Output 2
```

But when I write the same code inside a for loop

```
function getCount(objects) {
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<= objects.length; i++) {
      if (objects[i]['x'] == objects[i]['y']) {
          counter ++;
      }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Then I get a error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined**

Comment: `i<= objects.length` should be `i < objects.length`. In JS, indexes start at 0. So if your Array has 10 elements, the last index will be 9

Comment: `objects[objects.length]` will be `undefined` since the first item is at index `0`.

Comment: You should get comfortable reading the errors you receive and using `console.log` to debug - for example if you inspect the error, see what line number it's coming from, you would deduce your objects[i] is undefined, then you would log objects[i], then keep logging until you find the issue.

Comment: Thank you blex, code works now